# PlatformIO cannot find a working 3.6+ python interpreter to use with WSL

Tags: python, embedded, windows-subsystem-for-linux, platformio

As the title states, I am currently trying to set up PlatformIO with WSL in Ubuntu. If I type:

```
which python3
```

I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

however placing it as a full path for an executable does not work. I am currently running python 3.10 on Ubuntu WSL, so I know that the Python version is not an issue. How can I remedy this issue?

I tried to input the file path obtained from the bash terminal as a full file path and it does not work. Should I place the absolute file path from windows to WSL python.exe in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Run the given command on your Linux device.

```
sudo apt install -y python3-venv
```

Then restart your IDE. Ready to go!